# Applying weightings to nodes/intersections in OSMNX

Tags: nodes, osmnx

I've been searching for a way to apply weightings to the nodes/intersections themselves on OSMNX as opposed to the edges. Anyone know or figured out if the package allows for nodes to be given weightings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar to the answer by Debjit Bhowmick, you could do this more efficiently directly with Networkx:

```py
import networkx as nx
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_place('Piedmont, CA, USA', network_type='drive')

# create node weights
w = {k: 3 if v == 'turning_circle' else 1 for k, v in G.nodes(data='highway')}
nx.set_node_attributes(G, w, 'weight')
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to construct a `geodataframe` from the extracted OSMnx graph. Consequently, you may add an additional column where you can assign weights based on your preferred criteria.

In the following example, I have assigned a weight of 1.0 to all the nodes, except the ones that constitute a `traffic_signal`. For those, I have assigned a weight of 3.0.

```
import osmnx as ox
G = ox.graph_from_bbox( -37.8051, -37.7915, 144.9548, 144.9666, network_type='drive')
nodes = ox.graph_to_gdfs(G, nodes=True, edges=False)
nodes['weight'] = 1.0
for i in range(0,len(nodes)):
    if nodes['highway'].iloc[i] == 'traffic_signals':
        nodes['weight'].iloc[i] = 3.0

print(nodes.head())

                    y           x       osmid          highway                     geometry  weight
1725216770 -37.804785  144.964815  1725216770              NaN  POINT (144.96482 -37.80479)     1.0
2209383436 -37.794562  144.958250  2209383436              NaN  POINT (144.95825 -37.79456)     1.0
137181198  -37.800589  144.965390   137181198  traffic_signals  POINT (144.96539 -37.80059)     3.0
324235283  -37.798423  144.965710   324235283              NaN  POINT (144.96571 -37.79842)     1.0
1954066453 -37.795703  144.956705  1954066453              NaN  POINT (144.95670 -37.79570)     1.0
```